# 'Uncaught ReferenceError: ... is not defined' when calling a class (defined in module) from a browser console, JS

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a file class.js

```
            //implementation details
            const _stackCollection = new WeakMap();


            //interface
            export class Stack {

                constructor() {
                    _stackCollection.set(this, []);
                }

                get count() {
                    return _stackCollection.get(this).length;
                }

                pop() {
                    if (this.count === 0)
                        throw new Error('Nothing to pop');

                    return _stackCollection.get(this).pop();
                }

                peek() {
                    if (this.count === 0)
                        throw new Error('Nothing to peek');

                    return _stackCollection.get(this)[this.count - 1];
                }

                push(e) {
                    _stackCollection.get(this).push(e);
                    return;
                }

            }
```

and a module that imports given class looks like this 
module.js:

```
   import {Stack} from './class.js';
```

The index.html looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>hello world</h1>


    <script type="module" src='module.js'></script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

When I try to initialize the instance of Stack in a console I get the following error. There are many questions regarding the given error but I can not see anything would help me:

```
    const stack=new Stack()

    Uncaught ReferenceError: Stack is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

Comment: Did you intend to have two closing html tags?

Comment: when you do `export variable`, you need to import it as is. Try
`import Stack from './class.js';`

Comment: @yaswanth he is importing it. Since it's a named export, his import syntax is also correct. What he didn't show is the expression that triggers error

Comment: @AluanHaddad this is a phrase const stack=new Stack()

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, neither in Chrome, nor in Firefox, if `module.js` contains only `import {Stack} from './class.js'; console.dir(new Stack)` then a new object that is an instance of `Stack` is logged.

Comment: Can you post a minimal version of `module.js` that if copied allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Of course it won't be available in the browser console. That's expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declarations in a module are scoped to that module. If you want to access them, you need to import them.

To use such an export in your browser console, you need to import it or bind it to a global variable.

global (Note that this defeats the purpose of modules and should only be used for ad hoc testing)

```
export class A {}

// TODO: remove this
window.A = A;
```

With the proposed dynamic import syntax:

```
// browser console:
  import('./a.js').then(console.log);
```

**With SystemJS**

```
// browser console:
SystemJS.import('./a.js').then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your comments. As @AluanHaddad mentioned in a comment I cannot initialize the object class from console as I tried:

```
   const stack=new Stack()
```

Instead I may initialize it in module.js and than refrence it in window object as it is in Aluan answer. I rewritten module.js this way:

```
 import {Stack} from './class.js';

 const c = new Stack();
 c.push('a');

 window.c = c;
```

and then I can access object c from console

```
    >c
    >Stack {}
```

Comment: Note that this defeats the purpose of modules and should only be used for ad hoc testing